# Why would seal team prefer war paint over face mask in the late 22nd century?

Tags: warfare, military

My story is set in the late 22nd century C.E. despite the advancement in military technology to combat terrorism as well as against threats posed by hostile nations, elite units such as SEAL team are being deployed into action without face mask. How can I convinced my audience that war paint on the face is not for show but that it is part of the winning strategy in ensuring the success of the operation and regardless day or night and location beside ballrooms? I will not accept reason like psychology warfare as that is too obvious!

Comment: Does camouflage count as psychology?

Comment: Are you talking camouflage war paint, or some of the bright obnoxious warpaint used by tribes?

Comment: Upvote good questions, too!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- Even 150 years from now, the human eyes, ears, nose, and brain are still one of the best pattern recognition tools when it comes to split-second, shoot/no shoot decisions. A face mask dulls these senses.
- When you crawl through the mud, your face mask gets muddy. [Self-cleaning surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotus_effect) are not practical for your application. Incompatible with stealth? Not good enough?
- Automated sensors are really good at detecting machine-made shapes. So the face mask would scream "soldier" while face paint says "dirty human".
- Seal teams specialize in covert insertion and exfiltration. They can't use a [powered exoskeleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powered_exoskeleton) or a robot to haul their gear. Every pound of weight counts, and face paint is lighter than a mask. They'd rather pack an extra magazine for their rifle.

Pick one ...

Comment: I like it all! I've been through chemical warfare training, and this stuff is all true. I might recommend including respiration issues, as breathing through a mask can be problematic, and artificial breathing apparatus is usually bulky.

Answer (score 3):

The face paint is semi-permanent and seeps into the skin and doesn't come off for weeks. If a soldier is captured and held for ransom, the government will claim it isn't one of their soldiers and that it is a fake ransom request, otherwise they would show their face. This allows them to discredit the enemy.

Also the paint changes color instantly with an encrypted remote control so they can go from infiltrating a ballroom in the dark to show-time makeup to make them look like the skin color of the enemy and back to stealth to hunt down the hostages/enemy plans, like James Bond.

Comment: I like it!  The face paint *is* the mask!